# What does quantum mechanics have to say about energy density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, time, time-dilation

Increasing a system's energy density implies increasing certainty about its energy and position. This implies a large *un*certainty about the system's time and momentum. Since we know that large energy densities cause time dilation, are the corresponding uncertainties in time and momentum related to the emergence of time dilation?

Comment: What do you mean by: "increasing a system's energy density implies increasing certainty about its energy and position?"

Comment: I guess maybe I fumbled the wording a bit there. Energy density would be energy per unit volume. So, as you increase a system's energy density, you're either adding more energy or localizing what energy you have more precisely. So, whether you're measuring a change in energy or a change in the distribution of that energy, as you increase a system's energy density, your information and, therefore, certainty about the system's energy and position increases.

Comment: Uncertainty is related to the dispersion of measurement (or the second moment of non-commuting observables), not its absolute value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle

Comment: Quillo, I'm not sure I understand your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I want to stress the semantic point that dilation is not the same as uncertainty. Second, coming to your actual question, my take is that there is no connection and there is an apparent confusion.

The most important point that you should know is that time is a weird beast in quantum mechanics. It is the only "everyday" quantity that is not an observable variable in QM. Instead it is a $\it{parameter}$ that determines the evolution but has no corresponding operator and hence does not have an uncertainty associated with it (one side consequence of this is that Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ has no conjugate operator and is not defined $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ which makes Schoedinger's Equation an $\it{equation}$ and not an identity, hence saving our Universe from dullness). Therefore there is no Heisenberg commutation relation for time-energy and hence no corresponding uncertainty principle.

Now in your question you must be referring to the famous relations of the type $\Delta E \Delta t \sim h$ that you might often see here and there. The answer is that this relations are not wrong of course, but the meaning they carry is very different from the expressions of the sort $\Delta p \Delta x > h$. The latter is what it is, a limit on the product of dispersions. The former, as I tried to articulate in the previous paragraph, is meaningless in that sense. As Landau put it once, no one can prohibit you from calculating the energy of the ground state of a hydrogen atom (stationary state, hence $\Delta E=0$) and look at the clock ($\Delta t=0$).
To give the energy-time uncertainty relation a meaning, one has to clarify what he/she means by $\Delta E$ and $\Delta t$ for each particular situation. It can be for instance the linewidth of an excited atomic state and its lifetime (another famous interpretation can be found here: DOI: 10.1007/978-3-642-74626-0_8).

To summarize, unlike relativity, time is a special beast in QM: it just "flows on" much in the sense of the absolute time of Newton's (hence the main difficulty in putting relativity and QM in full accord). You cannot introduce an uncertainty to it, nor can you dilate it, or change its flow anyhow. In classical QM time just sets the stage on which everything else plays out (within the relevant Hilbert space). This is very different from the World as Relativity sees it, hence time-energy relations in QM, - which only make sense when interpreted properly, - have nothing to do with relativistic time dilations.

Comment: The purpose of questions is to learn and you have taught me. Thank you for answering and not silently downvoting.